# Python: Why public and private instance attribute behave differently with property methods

Tags: python

1. Using **self.cost = cost**  in  ***__init__***,we are getting following output

   inside ***__init__***

   inside setter

   inside property

   100
2. Using **self._cost = cost**  in  ***__init__***,we are getting following output

   inside ***__init__***

   inside property

   100

   In the first point,inside setter is being called but not in point 2.

   ```
   class Book(object):
       def __init__(self,cost):
       print('inside __init__')
       self.cost = cost
       #self._cost = cost

       @property
       def cost(self):
           print('inside property')
           return self._cost

       @cost.setter
       def cost(self,value):
           print('inside setter')
           self._cost = value

   book = Book(100)
   print(book.cost)
   ```

Comment: Yes, because a property called `some_name` is activated when you use attribute `.some_name`. Note, `some_name` is not the same as `_some_name`. There is nothing special about a single underscore, it's just like any other valid Python identifier. In Python, there is only *privacy by convention*, if you want to go ahead and play around with the "private" `_some_name` the language will not stop you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not private vs. public, but your property name is `cost` so `self.cost = cost` triggers the property setter, but `self._cost` does not, because there is no property `_cost`. It will just assign new attribute `_cost`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code makes it clear for you. There are few things to be considered, the decorator name should match exactly with the member variable `cost` or `_cost`. Also, the return should be `_variablename`. So if your variable name is `_cost`, you must return `__cost`.

### **Here is the small code example.**

```
class Book_(object):
def __init__(self,cost):
    print('inside __init__')
    self._cost = cost

    @property
    def _cost(self):
        print('inside property')
        return self.__cost

    @_cost.setter
    def _cost(self,value):
        print('inside setter')
        self.__cost = value

class Book(object):
    def __init__(self,cost):
        print('inside __init__')
        self.cost = cost

    @property
    def cost(self):
        print('inside property')
        return self._cost   ## see the difference with above

    @cost.setter ## see the difference with above
    def cost(self,value):
        print('inside setter')
        self._cost = value    ## see the difference with above
book = Book(10)
print(book.cost)
print('---')
book2 = Book_(100)
print(book2._cost)
```

**Output:**

```
inside __init__
inside setter
inside property
10
---
inside __init__
inside setter
inside property
100
```

---

Comment: In class Book_,why you put double underscore ( __cost). also why (_cost) in __init__ method.

Comment: You can think it as _ is nothing different but in case of some construct in python u should append a _ before your object to make use of certain features. Thats the case with returning __( double _)